# Extracting data from JSON files

Tags: mongodb, groovy

I have three JSON files "Friends" and followers.

friends: contains the information about friends and their tweets
followers: contains information about followers and their tweets
tweets: contains all tweets

I want to extract the following info and store it in a MongoDB collection named "friends"

id_str,
  name,
  description,
  favorites_count,
  followers_count,
  friends_count,
  language,
  location,
  screen_name,
  url,
  utc_offset

the tricky part for me is the "Each user (friend or follower) must contain its tweets in a new field tweet"

any suggestions on how to achieve that?

Here what I am doing at the moment:

```
JsonSlurper slurper = new JsonSlurper()
def friends = slurper.parseText(new File('./friends.json').text)
def followers = slurper.parseText(new File('./followers.json').text)
def tweets = slurper.parseText(new File('./tweets.json').text)

friends.users.forEach{ fr ->

    def frnds = mongo.friends << [
        [
            id_str: fr.id_str,
            name: fr.name,
            description: fr.description,
            favorites_count: fr.favourite_count,
            followers_count: fr.followers_count,
            friends_count: fr.friends_count,
            language: fr.language,
            location: fr.location,
            screen_name: fr.screen_name,
            url: fr.url,
            utc_offset: fr.utc_offset
        ]
    ]
}
```

Error: Exception in thread "main" groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: friends for class

Comment: Quick recap. You want to read in three separate "relational" files, and join them together to store in one collection? Probably the best way to explain is to "demonstrate". So if you can show a small sample from each file and how you want that data represented in your single document of the collection you create, then we can see what you mean. And help of course.

Answer (score 1):

you can use mongoose population method to display/store object of your user.

for example

```
followers:[{
    type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref:'follower'
}]
```

you can use reference user id and store in array just id will going to store in followers array and you can populate all ids in to object, so try to use `ref` in mongoose model.

this might look little bit confusing but consider looking this at [mongoose populate method](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) 
and also take a look at this [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FVn_wj1jLN0).

hope it helped!

Comment: How does this relate to the question? Or get upvotes for that matter. Question is about Groovy and JSON. I smell a voting ring here.